# Select different region on serverless based on branch

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I'm relative new on Serverless, I'm building now a lambda function and I need to deploy that same function on different stages and also different regions, for example for `development` stage I need to deploy to `us-est-1` region and for `production` stage I need to deploy to a different region, how can I do that using my branches, for example when I do a merge to `develop` use `us-est-1` region and then when code is merge to `master` branch use `us-est-2` region?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bash script and override the default serverless yl file definition.

for instance:

```yaml
provider:
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-1
```

then the script will check the branch and set environnement variables to override the default value (`dev` and `us-est-1`)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
MASTER='master'
DEVELOP='develop'

if [[ $BRANCH == $MASTER ]]; then
  STAGE="prod"
  AWS_REGION="us-west-2"
elif [[ $BRANCH == $DEVELOP ]]; then
  STAGE="dev"
  AWS_REGION="us-west-1"
fi

if [ -z ${STAGE+x} ]; then
  echo "Not deploying changes"
  exit 0
fi

echo "Prepare dependencies"
npm install

echo "Deploying from branch $BRANCH to stage $STAGE in region $AWS_REGION"

npx serverless deploy --stage $STAGE --region $AWS_REGION
```

Comment: This is the exact same we I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when you deploy you use

```
serverless deploy --stage development
```

or alternatively for master using the shorthand

```
sls deploy -s master
```

You could specify your regions to choose in the serverless.yml

```
provider:
region: ${self:custom.region.${self:custom.myStage}}

custom:
    myStage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
    region:
        production: us-east-2
        development: us-east-1
```

When merging it may depend on the CI/CD service you use to then state the stage depending on the branch, develop to development and production to master.